# Struggling to get framer-motion's exit animation working. [React.JS]

Tags: html, reactjs, framer-motion

RenderPokemonInfo.js:

```
const RenderPokemonInfo = (props) => {
    const pokemon = props.pokemonToUse;
    const pokemonCurrentTypes = [];
    let gradientString = "";

    const animateFromTop = {
      before: {
        y: '-100vh',
        opacity: 0,
      },
      onScreen: {
        y: '0',
        opacity: 1,
      },
      after: {
        y: '100vh',
        opacity: 0,
      }
    }

    pokemon.types.map((typeData) => {
        pokemonCurrentTypes.push(typeData.type.name);
    })

    if(pokemonCurrentTypes.length === 1) {
      gradientString = getGradient({typeString: pokemonCurrentTypes[0]});
    } else {
      gradientString = getGradient({typeString: pokemonCurrentTypes[0]}) + ', ' + getGradient({typeString: pokemonCurrentTypes[1]});
    }
    
    return (
      <>
      <motion.div variants={animateFromTop} initial='before' animate='onScreen' exit='after' key={pokemon.name}>
        <div style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '420px',
          height: '640px',
          left: '75%',
          top: '30px',
          transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
          backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(225deg, ' + gradientString + ')',
          boxShadow: '0 20px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
          borderRadius: '30px'}} key={'poke-pic-' + pokemon.name}>
          <fieldset className="poke-height-fieldset">
            <legend style={{position: 'absolute', left: '10px'}}>{pokemon.height * 10} cm</legend>
            <div className='big-poke-img-container'>
              <img src={'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/' + pokemon.id + '.svg'} className='big-poke-img'></img>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className='poke-type-container'>
              {pokemon.types.map((type) => <PokemonTypeButton typeString={type.type.name} isButton={false} key={type.type.name}/>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
      </>
    )
}

export default RenderPokemonInfo;
```

Part of my App.js that calls RenderPokemonInfo:

```
    <div className='content-container'>
        {(pokemon.length === 0) ? (
          <p>Pick a pokemon!</p>
        ) : (
          <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter={true}>
            <RenderPokemonInfo pokemonToUse={pokemon} key={pokemon.name}/>
          </AnimatePresence>
        )}
    </div>
```

When coming on screen the animations are fine, but when it leaves it just vanishes, no animation. I've seen on framer-motion's docs that you should put set the initial prop to false in AnimatePresence but when I do that it doesn't have an enter animation or an exit animation... am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is this entire component getting removed? If so, then you'll need to move the `AnimatePresence` tag up into the parent component. `AnimatePresence` watches for children getting removed from the DOM and runs the exit animation before removing them. If you have the `AnimatePresence` tag inside the component that gets removed, then it has no chance to run the exit animation, because the `AnimatePresence` tag is gone immediately along with the rest of the component.

You'd need something more like this (in your parent component):

```
<AnimatePresence>
    { pokemons.map(pokemon => <PokemonCard key={pokemon.name} />) }
</AnimatePresence>
```

And your `PokemonCard` would return the `motion.div` you show above (without the `AnimatePresence` tag)

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks! It still isn't working however, I've updated my post to show the whole class and the part of my App.js that renders it.

Answer (score 0):

This all came down to me not fully understanding how React uses keys. I used React.Child.toArray() to wrap everything I rendered from a map, this makes React give everything a unique key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).